# Creating Django Query Sets to Access Entire Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**UPDATE** I realized that my explanation below is kind of hiding what my real question is.  Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish is to create a dashboard.html template and be able to render access/data from my Traffic and Email models.

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

I am building a piece of software that will take inputed values and display them in a view - simple.  Currently I have two models/views with individual templates to view the data. This works as expected.

I am also creating a dashboard that should pull in data from both my models and this is the part that is causing me grief trying to wrap my mind around.  I read a lot on query sets, but can't find an example on how to implement into my project that I understand fully.

To give you an idea of what is rendered; this data is tabled data exported from Google Analytics, converted to csv and then imported into the application from Django admin.  The idea is to be able to view the data as a list using a 'for' loop and this works, the dashboard is being able to make visual graphs of the calculated data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not sure how much info you'll need, so I'll include as much as I can below.  Thank you.

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models


class Traffic(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    traffic = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    ifs_signups = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    campaigns = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    sales = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    def month(self):
        return self.date.strftime("%B")

    def quarter(self):
        item = self.date.strftime("%B")
        q1 = (["January", "February", "March"])
        q2 = (["April", "May", "June"])
        q3 = (["July", "August", "September"])
        q4 = (["October", "November", "December"])

        if item in q1:
            return "1st Quarter"
        elif item in q2:
            return "2nd Quarter"
        elif item in q3:
            return "3rd Quarter"
        elif item in q4:
            return "4th Quarter"
        else:
            return "No Date Specified"

    def conversions(self):
        conversion = self.sales / self.traffic
        return "%r" % conversion


class Email(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_list = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recipients = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    unsubscribes = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    bounces = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    open = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    clicks = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

    def month(self):
        return self.date.strftime("%B")

    def open_rate(self):
        open_rate = self.open / self.recipients
        return "%r" % open_rate

    def click_through_rate(self):
        click_through_rate = self.clicks / self.open
        return "%r" % click_through_rate
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Traffic
from .models import Email


class TrafficListView(ListView):
    model = Traffic
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/traffic.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrafficListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


class EmailListView(ListView):
    model = Email
    template_name = 'dashboard/pages/email.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmailListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Comment: I don't know what your question is. Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: Sorry, my question is how do I make a view so my dashboard.html template can use data from my Traffic and Email models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest breaking away from ListView and implementing a simple [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) of your own.

```
from myapp.models import Traffic, Email

class DashboardView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "dashboard/pages/dashboard.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['email_list'] = Email.objects.all()
        context['traffic_list'] = Traffic.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what I've been reading about, but your answer confirmed it.  Can you please give me an example of how I would reference the template tags in dashboard.html to render a list from lets say, Traffic?  In my traffic template I use {% for traffic in object_list %}{% endfor %}, but this isn't working in my dashboard template.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, the context objects are available as variable names in the template. So: `{% for traffic in traffic_list %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Brilliant!!  Thank you so much!!